# Form validation for big form

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I'm trying to make a form that checks for empty fields, proper email and phone number format, and only letters and spaces for names. I have tried many different websites but non work. Here is my code, I hope that you can suggest corrections.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
            E-Mail:<input type="text" id="email" size="15"/>
            <br/>
            Name:<input type="text" id="name" size="10"/>
            Phone #:<input type="text" id="phonenumber" size="15"/>
            Age:<input type="text" size="5" id="age"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkForm(email,inputtxt){  
    //Do I have to define the function parameters somewhere?
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]     {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);

    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (inputtxt.value.match(letters)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter a valid name!");
        return false;
    }

    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
    if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)){  
        return true;  
    }  
    else {  
        alert("Please insert a valid phone number!!!");  
        return false;  
    }  
    txb.value = txb.value.replace(/[^\0-9]/ig, ""); 
}
```

**Note: Don't criticize me on the JavaScript and/or HTML please. I got it from a website. I know most of you that respond know much more about coding than me, so can you please just try to help?**

Comment: "but non work". Describe "what" doesn't work. What you expect and what you get instead of that.

Answer (score 1):

you did not call the form validate function when you click on submit button

you can call validate function like this

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="history.forward()" />
```

Hope it will help you 
let me know if you need further clarification

thanks

Comment: Ashu, I am trying to make it check the form instead of submitting when u type in nothing. Hope you can help me with that. I thought I called the check function with the onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

```
E-Mail:<input type="email" id="email" size="15" required />
<br/>
Name:<input type="text" id="name" size="10" required />
Phone #:<input type="text" id="phonenumber" size="15"/>
Age:<input type="number" size="5" id="age" required />
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"/>
```

no extra function needed, hope its help :)